# Laravel Eloquent Max and Min Decimal from Multiple Tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on an auction site with two tables (listings and bids). The listings table allows users to set a buy-now price and a starting price. The bids table keeps track of each bid that is placed. I'm trying to create a search that will sort based on the highest price or lowest price. How can I find the highest or lowest price when the value can be multiple options (starting price, buy now price, or offer amount)? Currently, I am using orderByRaw, but its not showing the correct order:

```
$order_by = 'bids.offer_amount DESC, listings.buy_now_price DESC, listings.auction_start_price DESC';
$listings->orderByRaw($order_by)->get();
```

I have a helper function that gets the current price of an item, is there a way to use this function from within the eloquent call?

```
function currentPrice($id)
{
    // Look for sold bids first
    $sold = DB::table('bids')
        ->where('listing_id', $id)
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('offer_accepted', 1)
                ->orWhere('buy_now_accepted', 1);
        })
        ->first();

    $current_price = 0;

    if ($sold) {
        if (!empty($sold->offer_amount)) {
            $current_price = $sold->offer_amount;
        }
        if (!empty($sold->buy_now_amount)) {
            $current_price = $sold->buy_now_amount;
        }
    }

    if (empty($current_price)) {
        $current_set_price = Bid::where('listing_id', $id)->orderBy('max_bid_amount', 'desc')->skip(1)->first();
        if ($current_set_price) {
            $current_price = $current_set_price->max_bid_amount + 1;
        } else {
            // No Second Bid look for starting bid amount
            $listing = Listing::where('id', $id)->first();

            if ($listing) {
                $auction_start_price = $listing->auction_start_price;
                $current_price = $auction_start_price;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $current_price;
}
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL? If so, you can use IF() conditions in your select statement and order it by the alias, or maybe the GREATEST() function is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Ezycod yes its running on MySQL, haven't worked with IF or GREATEST before, wasn't sure if Eloquent had anything available before I used raw sql.

Comment: I don't think that Eloquent has anything like that, so you probably need to use raw SQL for that, take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest

Comment: I was able to get it to work using the IF conditions in MySQL, thanks

Comment: Maybe post your solution as an answer